# Need help linkifying taggings, but I want multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to create a method in my tag helper method class to turn "#hashtags", "@usertags", and "$moneytags" into links when someone posts one. It is supposed to find each of these tags and turn the entire word into a link. I know it works without the `||`, but I need it do do it if any of them are true.

Right now it tags the usertags, but not the others. I know the REGEXs are correct, however, I don't think the `||` ORs are supposed to work like that.

Is there a more efficient way to search each of these in one method? If I used three methods, one for each tag, I would have three repeated posts because my method reads the post and spits back out the entire post with the tags as links.

This was originally three methods, but because of this issue I have to have it all in the same method. It's supposed to be how twitter and other sites that use tags would do it.

I probably should also say I am creating this as a gem that anyone can use. Any suggestions or help?

```
def linkify_tags(taggable_content)
    regex = Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX
    tagged_content = taggable_content.to_s.gsub(regex) do
      link_to($&, tag_path($2), {class: :tag})
    end
    tagged_content.html_safe ||
    regex = Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX
    tagged_content = taggable_content.to_s.gsub(regex) do
      link_to($&, tag_path($2), {class: :tag})
    end
    tagged_content.html_safe ||
    regex = Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX
    tagged_content = taggable_content.to_s.gsub(regex) do
      link_to($&, tag_path($2), {class: :tag})
    end
    tagged_content.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: A tip for using tags: Use ones that have followers. For instance, [tag:ruby-on-rails] has a lot more people watching than does [tag:ruby-on-rails-4], and [tag:helpers] and [tag:#hashtag] are basically worthless.

Comment: I thought so, but I just put in 5 because it allowed me to use 5 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
REGEXS = [Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX]

def linkify_tags(taggable_content)
  text = taggable_content.to_s

  REGEXS.each do |regex|
    text = text.gsub(regex) { link_to($&, tag_path($2), class: 'tag') }
  end     

  text.html_safe
end
```

The problem with your code is that

```
tagged_content.html_safe ||
regex = Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX
```

is the same then `(tagged_content.html_safe || regex) = Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX`. This is probably not what you want. Since `tagged_content.html_safe` is always `true`, `regex` is not updated.

Comment: wrong argument type Array (expected Regexp) is what it's giving me. When I capitalize the Regexp it gives me the formal argument cannot be a constant.

Comment: I had a typo the my answer: `regexp` instead of `regex`. Updated my answer. Try again.

Comment: Thank you it works! I knew I should have done a loop. I was looking at if elsif statements for it as well. Thank you again!